# Two-Pane List-Details Activity - Reuse Fragment or Instantiate New Fragment Per Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have a list fragment and a details fragment in my activity. When choosing an item in the list, the existing details fragment object's contents are changed to reflect the current selection. This keeps it instantaneous since there is no additional layout inflation or object instantiation.

However each time a new item is shown I must start a long running AsyncTask that must run to completion even if the user selects a different item. If the user comes back to a previous item it must display the current state of the previously created AsyncTask.

Is it worthwhile dealing with this management overhead so that I can reuse a single fragment instance or should I just instantiate a new self-contained fragment instance for each item? If I choose the latter, when should I dispose of "old" fragments?

It's also worth noting that in the "phone" version of the two-pane SDK sample a new fragment is created each time an item is selected since the fragment is displayed in a completely new activity. However since I'm using a SlidingPaneLayout, even the phone version will use just a single activity for both the list and details.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354

Comment: Fixed. It's more of an A or B question.